# Order of factor levels in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to produce a facet_wrap where the order of factors within facets is
based on the one of the column factor order. The heart of the problem is each group has duplicated factor levels and when I do plotting only one factor level is ordered correctly in the `facet_wrap`. (See the graph below)

I try to order factor levels in each group and each factor level should be ordered correctly inside of each facet.

Here is my attempt

```
df_pattern<- data.frame(address = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:3]),3)) 

df_TP <- data.frame(No=rep(seq(1:3)),
                    clas=c("Good","Bad","Ugly"),stringsAsFactors = F)

set.seed(12)
df_ex <- df_pattern%>%
  mutate(No=rep(seq(1:3),each=3))%>%
  left_join(df_TP)%>%
  mutate(clas=sample(clas))%>%
  group_by(No)

#      address    No  clas
#       <fctr> <int> <chr>
#    1       A     1  Good
#    2       B     1  Ugly
#    3       C     1  Ugly
#    4       A     2  Good
#    5       B     2  Ugly
#    6       C     2   Bad
#    7       A     3   Bad
#    8       B     3   Bad
#    9       C     3  Good
```

Now lets try to sort address levels according to user defined clas column order

```
set.seed(12)
df_ex <- df_pattern%>%
  mutate(No=rep(seq(1:3),each=3))%>%
  left_join(df_TP)%>%
  mutate(clas=sample(clas))%>%
  group_by(No)%>%
  mutate(clas=factor(clas,levels=c("Good","Bad","Ugly")))%>%
  mutate(address=factor(address,levels=unique(address[order(clas)])))%>%
  mutate(address=as.character(address))%>%
  arrange(No,clas) 

      address    No  clas
#       <fctr> <int> <ord>
#    1       A     1  Good
#    2       B     1  Ugly
#    3       C     1  Ugly
#    4       A     2  Good
#    5       C     2   Bad
#    6       B     2  Ugly
#    7       C     3  Good
#    8       A     3   Bad
#    9       B     3   Bad
```

As you can see only the `No=1` group ordered correctly in the plot. Maybe this because only one factor level in the data set.

```
> levels(df_ex$address)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

How can we order factor levels in each group and show them in the facet_wrap? according to `clas` levels in each `facet_wrap`?

Thanks!

ggplot code

```
ggplot(df_ex, aes(x=address,y="",fill=clas)) + #x axis bias voltage dependence
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('Good'="green","Bad"="Blue","Ugly"="black"))+
  facet_wrap(~No,ncol=1,scales = "free_x")+
  theme(legend.position = "top",axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20,angle = 90),axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,face="bold",colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 20, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 20 , colour = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=26, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="#FFFF66", colour="black", size=0.5),
        plot.title=element_text(face="bold",color="red",size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=26,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=18))+
  labs(x = "address",y = "")
```

[image]

Comment: @NathanDay sure. I am sorry I forgot:)

Comment: to my knowledge, currently ggplot doesn't let you define breaks or limits for each facet manually https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/187, so you are tied to the overall order of `df_ex$address` which here is "A,B,C" if you make 3 separate plots you could use `grid.arrange` or `cowplot::plot_grid` to build a similar figure.

Comment: @NathanDay I see your comment. I thought there is some solution made to this problem. But as you mentioned still not! I guess I will stick with grid.arrange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution makes each group unique and arranges in the desired order, then changes the names back to your original names.

```
df_ex$names<-paste(df_ex$address,df_ex$clas,df_ex$No)
df_ex$names<-factor(df_ex$names,levels=c("A Good 1","B Ugly 1","C Ugly 1", "A Good 2", "C Bad 2", "B Ugly 2", "C Good 3", "A Bad 3", "B Bad 3"))


ggplot(df_ex, aes(x=names,y="",fill=clas)) + #x axis bias voltage dependence
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('Good'="green","Bad"="Blue","Ugly"="black"))+
  facet_wrap(~No,ncol=1,scales = "free_x")+
  theme(legend.position = "top",axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20,angle = 90),axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,face="bold",colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 20, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 20 , colour = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=26, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="#FFFF66", colour="black", size=0.5),
        plot.title=element_text(face="bold",color="red",size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=26,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=18))+
  labs(x = "address",y = "")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=df_ex$names, labels=df_ex$address)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This old question has already an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203502/3817004). But as it is being used *as a dupe target*, I feel obliged to suggest a slightly improved and more concise variant.

It's based on the recent enhancements of the `ggplot2` package, namely the `labels` parameter to `scale_x_discrete()`, and Hadley's `forcats` package released to CRAN in August 2016. The proposed solution enhances the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203502/3817004) by using material from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183698/3817004).

#### Prepare data

`df_ex` as provided by the OP needs to be modified to include a variable which guarantees an overall sort order across all facets:

```
library(dplyr)   # version 0.5.0 used 
df_ex <- df_ex %>% mutate(ordered = paste0(No, address) %>% 
                   forcats::fct_inorder())
```

The additional column to `df_ex` now looks as follows:

```
  address    No   clas ordered
    <chr> <int> <fctr>  <fctr>
1       A     1   Good      1A
2       B     1   Ugly      1B
3       C     1   Ugly      1C
4       A     2   Good      2A
5       C     2    Bad      2C
6       B     2   Ugly      2B
7       C     3   Good      3C
8       A     3    Bad      3A
9       B     3    Bad      3B
```

As `df_ex` already had been sorted in the desired order using `arrange()`, `fct_inorder()` returns the new column `ordered` with the levels in the same order as their first appearance.

#### Plotting

Instead of `address`, `ordered` is plotted on the x-axis. The parameter `scales = "free_x"` to `facet_wrap()` ensures that unused levels will be dropped from the facets. However, the labels on the x-axis need to be be replaced by supplying a *named vector* to the `labels` parameter of `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
library(ggplot2)   # version 2.2.1 used
ggplot(df_ex, aes(x=ordered,y="",fill=clas)) + #x axis bias voltage dependence
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('Good'="green","Bad"="Blue","Ugly"="black"))+
  facet_wrap(~No,ncol=1,scales = "free_x")+
  theme(legend.position = "top",axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20,angle = 90),axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,face="bold",colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 20, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 20 , colour = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=26, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="#FFFF66", colour="black", size=0.5),
        plot.title=element_text(face="bold",color="red",size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=26,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=18))+
  labs(x = "address",y = "") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = setNames(df_ex$address, df_ex$ord)) +
```

[image]