# Reorder grouped bar plot within facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid

My third question today, learning a lot thanks all.

I am trying to reorder the bar groups within each facet by the `curr.data$Gap` variable. The Gap is the difference between the bars for each y label, and I need the order within each facet to go from the smallest to largest gap.

Slightly different to other reorder questions as I need to consider within-facet ordering.

Normally I could do this for a simple bar plot by factoring the data with set levels, though cannot make that work here.

Data:

```
structure(list(dept = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Distribution Centre Services", "IT", 
"Marketing", "Merchandise & Inventory", "Operations and Communication"
), class = "factor"), label = c("test 25", "test 23", "test 24", 
"test 27", "test 26", "test 28", "test 29", "test 31", "test 33", 
"test 30", "test 32", "test 38", "test 36", "test 37", "test 43", 
"test 34", "test 35", "test 40", "test 39", "test 42", "test 41", 
"test 25", "test 23", "test 24", "test 27", "test 26", "test 28", 
"test 29", "test 31", "test 33", "test 30", "test 32", "test 38", 
"test 36", "test 37", "test 43", "test 34", "test 35", "test 40", 
"test 39", "test 42", "test 41"), Gap = c(-0.16, -0.18, -0.21, 
-0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.31, -0.31, -0.35, -0.39, -0.42, -0.15, 
-0.15, -0.2, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.29, -0.31, -0.36, 
-0.16, -0.18, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, -0.31, -0.31, -0.35, 
-0.39, -0.42, -0.15, -0.15, -0.2, -0.21, -0.22, -0.27, -0.29, 
-0.29, -0.31, -0.36), section = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), impeff = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Effectiveness", "Importance"), class = "factor"), 
    score = c(0.77, 0.79, 0.82, 0.8, 0.83, 0.9, 0.91, 0.94, 0.89, 
    0.94, 0.91, 0.82, 0.74, 0.78, 0.81, 0.83, 0.85, 0.82, 0.81, 
    0.8, 0.83, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.58, 0.56, 0.61, 0.6, 0.63, 
    0.54, 0.55, 0.49, 0.67, 0.59, 0.58, 0.6, 0.61, 0.58, 0.53, 
    0.52, 0.49, 0.47)), .Names = c("dept", "label", "Gap", "section", 
"impeff", "score"), row.names = c(23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
curr.plot <- ggplot(data = curr.data, aes(x = label, y = score)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = impeff),stat = "identity", position = "dodge",width = .7) +
    geom_text(aes(label=percent(score),group=impeff), position= position_dodge(width=.7),vjust=.4,hjust=-.1) + 
    facet_grid(dept~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
    coord_flip()+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE,title=NULL))+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"))+
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(0,1))
```

Current output:
[image]

Comment: This question is different. It is to reorder WITH facets. It is not duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `x = label` with `x = reorder(label,Gap)`

Comment: Doesn't help when there are facets.

Comment: @Diogo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624394/ggplot-bar-plot-with-facet-dependent-order-of-categories