# Specifying custom plot order for each facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plot ordering with `facet_wrap` works ok when the order variables are not duplicated across the facets, e.g:

```
mtcars %>% arrange(mpg) %>% 
  mutate(car = row.names(mtcars), car = factor(car, levels = car)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(car, mpg)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales='free') + coord_flip()
```

[image]

When you try to repeat this for data where the ordering category duplicates factor items across the facets you get an error:

```
data.frame(x = c('a','b','c','a','b','c'), 
            y = c(4,2,1,3,5,7), grp = rep(c('A','B'), each=3)) %>% 
   arrange(-y) %>% mutate(x = factor(x, levels = x)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') +
   facet_wrap(~ grp, scales='free') + coord_flip()
Warning messages:
1: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
2: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
3: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
4: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

If we can't use factors is there any other way to order the plot facets individually in line with the `mtcars` example?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183698/3817004

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens when you set the levels of `x`. `ggplot` doesn't know how to deal with multiple levels with the same name, so the function fails. If you set that to `levels = unique(x)` it does work:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = c('a','b','c','a','b','c'), 
           y = c(4,2,1,3,5,7), grp = rep(c('A','B'), each=3)) %>% 
    arrange(-y) %>% mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    facet_wrap(~ grp, scales='free') + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Sraffa this isn't quite what I'm after - I need both facets to order downwards from biggest to smallest..

Comment: I see. I added a flag for the question being a duplicate, I think the link will help.