# Group by category and sort alphabetically with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to sort alphabetically the name of the species that appear in the data frame, but in turn, they have to be ordered by the category assigned in the "Vuln" column. In my code, the first part is resolved, but I can not group the appearance of the species in the figure by its category.

I tried that ggplot used the order of the data frame data, but I did not get it. My knowledge about R is limited by the little time I have been using it, basically I learn based on trial and error.

```
df1 <- read.csv(file=paste(di,"/specieorder.csv", sep=""), header=TRUE, sep=";")

# Change order (allphabetically) to improve the plot
df1 <- within(df1, Specie_ord <- ordered(Specie, levels=rev(sort(unique(Specie)))))
df1<- df1[df1$Group.1!=' ', ]

str(df1)
df1$Zone <- as.factor(df1$Zone)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df1, aes(Zone,Specie_ord)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=x), shape=15, col='darkred') + 
  scale_size('Number\nof\nRecords')+
  theme_bw() +facet_grid(.~Fire) +
  xlab('Zone') + ylab('Species')
p + ggtitle("Abundance by species") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=12))
```

I attach the file with the data in .csv format "delimited by commas"
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cOZv39XkxuM64LLXYiLTd_ujUSKeRnPL

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for but might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214383/786542

Comment: Thanks for the thread, it is a possible option. Although the possibility of grouping the data of a matrix by several variables is what it was trying to achieve. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to order your `Specie` first according to `Vuln` and within each  `Vuln` according to `Specie`? If this is the case you can use the following snippet:

```
df1$Specie_ord_vuln_name <- factor(df1$Specie,
                                   rev(unique(df1$Specie[order(df1$Vuln, df1$Specie)])))
```

What the code does is to create a new factor (`Specie_ord_vuln_name`). In `ggplot` factors are ordered according to their levels. Thus, you have to assign the levels in the order you want for your plot. We use the `order` function to get the order of the observation by `Vuln` and within `Vuln` by `Specie`. We use `rev` to reverse the levels to have them from top to down. Then you can plot it:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Zone, Specie_ord_vuln_name)) + 
   geom_point(aes(size = x), shape = 15, col = 'darkred') + 
   scale_size('Number\nof\nRecords')+
   theme_bw() + facet_grid(.~Fire) +
   xlab('Zone') + ylab('Species') +
   ggtitle("Abundance by species") + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12))
```

[image]

Comment: Exact! This is what I was trying to achieve, but I was not able. Thank you very much @thothal, for the code and the explanation