# generate seasonal plot, but with fiscal year start/end dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

**Hello! Is there a way to index a chart to start and end at specific points
(which may be out of numeric order)?**

I have data that begins October 1st, and ends September 31st the following year. The series repeats through multiple years past, and i want to build a daily seasonality chart. The challenge is the X axis is not from low to high, it runs 10-11-12-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9.

**Question 1:**

Can you order the index by month 10-11-12-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9?
while, being compatible with %m-%d formatting, as the real problem is in 
daily format, but for the sake of brevity, I am only using months.

[image]

the result should look something like this...sorry i had to use excel...

**Question 2:**

Can we remove the connected chart lines, or will the solution to 1, naturally fix
question 2? examples in the attempts below.

**Question 3:**

Can the final formatting of the solution allow to take a moving average, or other 
mutations of the initial data? The table in attempt #2 would allow to take the average of each month by year. Since July 17 is 6 and July 18 is 12, we would plot a 9 in the chart, ect for the entire plot.

**Question 4:**

Is there and XTS equivalent to solve this problem?

***THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!***

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2016-10-1"), as.Date("2018-09-01"), by="month")
values <- c(2,3,4,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11,12,13,11,12,13,14)
YearEnd <-c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,
        2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018)
df <- data.frame(Date,values,YearEnd)

## PLOT THE TIMESERIES
plot_ly(df, x = ~Date, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
```

[image]

```
## PLOT THE DATA BY MONTH: attempt 1
df$Month <- format(df$Date, format="%m")

df2 <- df %>% 
  select(values, Month, YearEnd)
plot_ly(df2, x = ~Month, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", 
    connectgaps = FALSE)

## Plot starts on the 10th month, which is good, but the index is 
## in standard order, not 10-11-12-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
## It also still connects the gaps, bad.
```

[image]

```
## CREATE A PIVOTTABLE: attempt 2
table <- spread(df2,YearEnd, values)
df3 <- melt(table ,  id.vars = 'Month', variable.name = 'series')
plot_ly(df3, x = ~Month, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", 
    connectgaps = FALSE)

## now the data are in the right order, but the index is still wrong
## I also do not understand how plotly is ordering it correctly, as 2
## is not the starting point in January.
```

[image]

Comment: I dont understand what's wrong with the first plot?

Comment: @Tung - yes, nothing is wrong with the first plot. Just shows the plain time-series. I am attempting to overlay the 2017 and 2018 data on a 10-11-12-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 monthly scale for the x-axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set the desired `levels` for the `Month` inside `factor`

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2016-10-1"), as.Date("2018-09-01"), by = "month")
values <- c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13, 14)
YearEnd <- c(
  2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017,
  2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018
)
df <- data.frame(Date, values, YearEnd)


# to fiscal year order
df %<>%
  mutate(
    Month = month(Date),
    YearEnd = factor(YearEnd)) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month,
    levels = c(10:12, 1:9),
    labels = c(month.abb[10:12], month.abb[1:9])))
df

#>          Date values YearEnd Month
#> 1  2016-10-01      2    2017   Oct
#> 2  2016-11-01      3    2017   Nov
#> 3  2016-12-01      4    2017   Dec
#> 4  2017-01-01      3    2017   Jan
#> 5  2017-02-01      4    2017   Feb
#> 6  2017-03-01      5    2017   Mar
#> 7  2017-04-01      6    2017   Apr
#> 8  2017-05-01      4    2017   May
#> 9  2017-06-01      5    2017   Jun
#> 10 2017-07-01      6    2017   Jul
#> 11 2017-08-01      7    2017   Aug
#> 12 2017-09-01      8    2017   Sep
...

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(
  x = Month, y = values,
  color = YearEnd,
  group = YearEnd)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12)

ggplotly(p1)
```

[image]

---

**Edit: to plot by Julian day**, we use a similar method to the 3rd one from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214383/786542)

```r
# Generate random data
set.seed(2018)

date = seq(from = as.Date("2016-10-01"), to = as.Date("2018-09-30"),
           by = "days")
values = c(rnorm(length(date)/2, 8, 1.5), rnorm(length(date)/2, 16, 2))
dat <- data.frame(date, values)

df <- dat %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(jday    = factor(yday(date)),
         Month   = month(date),
         Year    = year(date),
         # only create label for the 1st day of the month
         myLabel = case_when(day(date) == 1L ~ format(date, "%b-%d"),
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  # create fiscal year column
  mutate(fcyear = case_when(Month > 9 ~ as.factor(Year + 1),
                            TRUE      ~ as.factor(Year))) %>% 
  mutate(Month = factor(Month,
                        levels = c(10:12, 1:9),
                        labels = c(month.abb[10:12], month.abb[1:9])))
df

#> # A tibble: 730 x 7
#>    date       values jday  Month  Year myLabel fcyear
#>    <date>      <dbl> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <chr>   <fct> 
#>  1 2016-10-01   7.37 275   Oct    2016 Oct-01  2017  
#>  2 2016-10-02   5.68 276   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  3 2016-10-03   7.90 277   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  4 2016-10-04   8.41 278   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  5 2016-10-05  10.6  279   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  6 2016-10-06   7.60 280   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  7 2016-10-07  11.1  281   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  8 2016-10-08   9.30 282   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#>  9 2016-10-09   7.08 283   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#> 10 2016-10-10   8.96 284   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017  
#> # ... with 720 more rows


# Create a row number for plotting to make sure ggplot plot in
# the exact order of a fiscal year
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(fcyear) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
df1

#> # A tibble: 730 x 8
#>    date       values jday  Month  Year myLabel fcyear order
#>    <date>      <dbl> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <chr>   <fct>  <int>
#>  1 2016-10-01   7.37 275   Oct    2016 Oct-01  2017       1
#>  2 2016-10-02   5.68 276   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       2
#>  3 2016-10-03   7.90 277   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       3
#>  4 2016-10-04   8.41 278   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       4
#>  5 2016-10-05  10.6  279   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       5
#>  6 2016-10-06   7.60 280   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       6
#>  7 2016-10-07  11.1  281   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       7
#>  8 2016-10-08   9.30 282   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       8
#>  9 2016-10-09   7.08 283   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017       9
#> 10 2016-10-10   8.96 284   Oct    2016 <NA>    2017      10
#> # ... with 720 more rows

# plot with `order` as x-axis 
p2 <- ggplot(df1, 
             aes(x = order, y = values,
              color = fcyear,
              group = fcyear)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) +
  xlab(NULL)

# now replace `order` label with `myLabel` created above
x_break <- df1$order[!is.na(df1$myLabel)][1:12]
x_label <- df1$myLabel[x_break]
x_label

#>  [1] "Oct-01" "Nov-01" "Dec-01" "Jan-01" "Feb-01" "Mar-01" "Apr-01"
#>  [8] "May-01" "Jun-01" "Jul-01" "Aug-01" "Sep-01"

p3 <- p2 +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = x_break,
    labels = x_label) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_color_brewer("Fiscal Year", palette = "Dark2") +
  xlab(NULL)
p3
```

[image]

```r
ggplotly(p3)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thank you very much Tung. My actual sample data is in daily format.                    
                                                                                                                                 
So my x axis becomes... df$MD <- format(df$Date, format="%m-%d"). Can factors be the solution for this additional level of complexity?

Comment: You can probably create a `Day` vector from `1:365` then move the days corresponding to Oct:Dec in front of days from Jan:Sep just like I did with Month

Comment: I'm sorry but i am very new at this. The max days in any month would be 31, so the largest number for October would be 10-31 for the x axis index. Would you mind showing an example please?

Comment: This is the code i would use to get everything into daily format: dateindex<-tibble::tibble(Date = seq(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by = "1 day"))

dfdaily <- left_join(dateindex, df, by = "Date") %>% 
    mutate(
      yr = year(Date),
      month = month(Date),
      day = day(Date)
    ) %>% 
    fill(everything())

dfdaily$MD <- format(dfdaily$Date, format="%m-%d")

Comment: @Joe: what I meant was you need to use Julian day from 1 to 365 https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html

Comment: Thanks man, you are a beast. This is really great stuff. You taught me multiple new concepts here. And you even helped a Vandal, which i appreciate :) small world... Go Cougs! Bonus, is there a way to get the Month and day to show up on the chart when i switch over to plotly? This would take the place of the Order: ###. Thanks for everything - Joe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179703/discussion-between-joe-and-tung).

Comment: @Joe: You're welcome! Glad that I could help :) Unfortunately I don't know how to do it in `plotly`

Answer (score 2):

Consider this an appendix to Tung's excellent answer. Here I've made it obvious how to alter the code for different start and end months of financial (or production) years which varies by country (and industry), with the Parameter `EndMonth`. I've also added an annual average, which seems like a pretty obvious thing to want as well (though outside the OP's request).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

## Generate random data
set.seed(2018)

date = seq(from = as.Date("2016-06-01"), to = as.Date("2016-06-01")+729,
           by = "days") # about 2 years, but even number of days
values = c(rnorm(length(date)/2, 8, 1.5), rnorm(length(date)/2, 16, 2))
dat <- data.frame(date, values)

EndMonth <- 5 #i.e. if last month of financial year is May, use 5 for 5th month of calendar year

df <- dat %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(jday    = factor(yday(date)),
         Month   = month(date),
         Year    = year(date),
         # only create label for the 1st day of the month
         myLabel = case_when(day(date) == 1L ~ format(date, "%b%e"),
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  # create fiscal year column
   mutate(fcyear = case_when(Month > EndMonth ~ as.factor(Year + 1),
                             TRUE      ~ as.factor(Year))) %>% 
  mutate(Month = factor(Month,
                        levels = c((EndMonth+1):12, 1:(EndMonth)),
                        labels = c(month.abb[(EndMonth+1):12], month.abb[1:EndMonth])))
df



#make 2 (or n)  year average
df_mean <-  df %>% 
  group_by(jday) %>% 
  mutate(values = mean(values, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(fcyear %in% c("2017")) %>%  #note hard code for first fcyear in dataset
  mutate(fcyear = "Average")

#Add average to data frame
df <-  bind_rows(df, df_mean)

# Create a row number for plotting to make sure ggplot plot in
# the exact order of a fiscal year
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(fcyear) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
df1



# plot with `order` as x-axis 
p2 <- ggplot(df1, 
             aes(x = order, y = values,
                 color = fcyear,
                 group = fcyear)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) +
  xlab(NULL)
p2

# now replace `order` label with `myLabel` created above
x_break <- df1$order[!is.na(df1$myLabel)][1:12]
x_label <- df1$myLabel[x_break]
x_label

p3 <- p2 +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = x_break,
    labels = x_label) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_color_brewer("Fiscal Year", palette = "Dark2") +
  xlab(NULL)
p3
```

[image: annual plot]

Comment: Thanks Mark, This is a great addition