# R caret naïve bayes accuracy is null

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes

I have one [dataset](https://github.com/MarcosGrzeca/drunktweets/blob/master/chat/rdas/2gram-entidades-erro.Rda) to train with SVM and Naïve Bayes.
SVM works, but Naïve Bayes doesn't work. Follow de source code below:

```
library(tools)
library(caret)
library(doMC)
library(mlbench)
library(magrittr)
library(caret)

CORES <- 5 #Optional
registerDoMC(CORES) #Optional

load("chat/rdas/2gram-entidades-erro.Rda")

set.seed(10)
split=0.60

maFinal$resposta <- as.factor(maFinal$resposta)
data_train <- as.data.frame(unclass(maFinal[ trainIndex,]))
data_test <- maFinal[-trainIndex,]

treegram25NotNull <- train(x = subset(data_train, select = -c(resposta)),
      y = data_train$resposta, 
      method = "nb",
      trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, savePred=T, sampling = "up"))

treegram25NotNull
```

The final accuracy is null
[image: yy]

> Warning messages:
>   1: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
>     There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
>   2: In train.default(subset(data_train, select = -c(resposta)), data_train$resposta,  :
>     missing values found in aggregated results

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `trainIndex` is currently undefined.

Comment: Sorry: trainIndex <- createDataPartition(maFinal$resposta, p=split, list=FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is really simple:

```
set.seed(10)
split <- 0.60
maFinal[] <- lapply(maFinal, as.factor)
```

Currently all your variables, except for `resposta`, are numeric. However, they have only up to 12~ distinct values, meaning that they all actually should be factor variables. Also, many of them are highly unbalanced. Then, when splitting the sample, the issue arises from treating (actually factor) variables with only a single unique value as continuous variables.

Comment: Thanks. It's work
maFinal[] <- lapply(maFinal, as.factor)