# Different reorder in ggplot2's facet_grid inner elements with multiple repeated values

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, facet-grid

This might be a very particular case I've been trying to accomplish but nevertheless quite useful. I need to sort ggplot2's facet_grid inner elements with multiple repeated values based on another variable. Example with a given data.frame `df` (shown below). When using `factor` you can define a specific order for its levels, but in this case, there are different orders because it is based in a third value, and in the example, for `var2 = TRUE`'s grid, `A` would be the first (ranked) element and for `var2 = FALSE`'s grid, `A` should be the last.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                 var2 = c('C','A','A','Z','C'),
                 n = c(5,10,1,3,3))
ggplot(df, aes(reorder(var2,n), n)) + 
  geom_col() + facet_grid(var1~.) + coord_flip()
```

[image: example ggplot2]

I wish to sort both grids by the `n` variable and the result should be C,Z,A for the `FALSE` grid and A,C,Z for the `TRUE` grid. There should by like an `ungroup()` function for `ggplot2`'s reorder...

**BONUS:** Even more complex, I have a tidyverse friendly function in the [lares library](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares) for calculating and plotting frequencies (`freqs`). It uses the `!!!variables` lazy evaluation for each variable and sometimes these variables might be more than one. For instance, `distr(df, var1, var2, var3)` or simply `distr(df, var1)`. That is why I can't (or at least I don't know how) dynamically convert these variables as sorted factors if that is the solution.

Is there a way to do this without the use of `cowplot` or `gridExtra` which makes different plots and then paste them all together? It is too slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214383/786542)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(var1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                 var2 = c('C','A','A','Z','C'),
                 n = c(5,10,1,3,3))

reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

ggplot(df, aes(reorder_within(var2, n, var1), n)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_grid(var1 ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Wow @tung What an incredible solution! I think this should be added to ggplot2 as an available option. It worked for me! And how would you add a third variable to this logic, using the same/edited function?

Comment: Have you tried all three methods in the linked answer & remove `scales = "free", space = "free"` inside `facet_grid` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I can get to solve that.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                 var2 = as.factor(c('C','A','A','Z','C')),
                 n = c(5, 10, 1, 3, 3))
df$var3 <- ifelse(df$var1, paste0(df$var2, 'T'), paste0(df$var2, 'F'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(var3, n), 
               y = n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(var1 ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @fernando 
I had thought about that as a solution but is aesthetically terrible. Any further ideas?