# facet_grid and reordering columns by y value

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a dataframe with country names, continent, year and some welfare indicators variables.

```
              country year infant_mortality life_expectancy fertility population
1             Albania 1960           115.40           62.87      6.19    1636054
2             Algeria 1960           148.20           47.50      7.65   11124892
3              Angola 1960           208.00           35.98      7.32    5270844
4 Antigua and Barbuda 1960               NA           62.97      4.43      54681
5           Argentina 1960            59.87           65.39      3.11   20619075
6             Armenia 1960               NA           66.86      4.55    1867396
           gdp continent          region
1           NA    Europe Southern Europe
2  13828152297    Africa Northern Africa
3           NA    Africa   Middle Africa
4           NA  Americas       Caribbean
5 108322326649  Americas   South America
6           NA      Asia    Western Asia
```

I would like to plot the life expectancy for each African country in 1970 and 2010 and re-order
the columns for each year in ascending order: the idea is to see whether there has been a change in the ranking.

This is what I have done.

```
gapminder %>% dplyr::filter(continent %in% "Africa" & year %in% c(1970, 2010)) %>% 
  mutate(country = reorder(country, life_expectancy, FUN = median)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= country, y = life_expectancy, fill = region)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(.~year) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust =1), legend.position = "none")
```

How can I re-order the levels of the factor for each facet?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214383/786542?

Comment: You also have a tutorial on how to do it here https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/