# How to generate sub-plots with grouped categorical variable sorted by a numeric variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, factors

I have a dataframe `text` with count `n` of `word` appearing in each file `file_num = 1 or 2 or 3`. I would like to use ggplot to generate three subplots, one for each value of `file_num`, with `word` on the y-axis and the frequency `n` on x-axis. I want each sub-plot to be sorted according to increasing or decreasing value of `n` observed withing each `file_num`. I have tried many different ways to solve this seemingly trivial issue but have not been successful.

Here is `dput` of my test data:

```
structure(list(file_num = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), word = c("test", "quality", 
"page", "limit", "information", "limit", "test", "instruments", 
"quality", "limit", "test", "effective", "page", "system"), n = c(5, 
35, 55, 75, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 101, 201, 301, 401, 501)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(file_num = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), word = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), n = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
text %>% group_by(file_num) %>% arrange(file_num, desc(n)) %>%
    ggplot(.,aes(factor(word,levels = unique(word)), n, fill = file_num)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_x_discrete("Word") +
    scale_y_continuous("n")  + coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(file_num), scales = "free")
```

Here is the plot that is generated using the above code on dataframe `text` created using the `dput` data.  It shows the desired result (`word` sorted with increasing value of `n`) for file_num = 1, but not for file_num = 2 or 3:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order data by value within ggplot facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214071/how-to-order-data-by-value-within-ggplot-facets)

Comment: Instead of all those library calls, a single library call to library(tidyverse) would also do the deal :)

Comment: This might also be of use - https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R

Comment: @Tjebo thanks for pointing in the right direction after a lot of wrangling I have a working solution. I will post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this "ordered per facet" quite simply with the `ggcharts` package, using the following code on your data:

```
library(ggcharts)
bar_chart(data = text, x = word, y = n, 
  fill = file_num,
  facet = file_num,
  horizontal = TRUE
)
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Please, let me know whether this is what you want.

Update:

The object created by `bar_chart` is of class `ggplot`, as can be seen below:

```
class(chart)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

This means that one can use the `ggplot2` functions to alter the graph, e.g.:

```
chart + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) +      ## remove legend 
  ggtitle("My new title") + ## add title
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "red", size = 2))
```

yielding the following pic (for illustration only) :

[image]

Comment: thanks I will accept your answer but I was really looking for a `ggplot` based approach.

Comment: @sachin2014 Actually, if you type `class(chart)`, you will see that it is a `ggplot`-object. This means that you can use the `ggplot2` package to alter it: e.g. `chart + ggtitle("My new title")`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tjebo for pointing me in the right direction. Here is a working solution that is based on `ggplot`. It does require one to save the modified dataframe `text` before using it in `ggplot`.

Let me know if there is a way to directly pipe the modified dataframe into `ggplot`

```
text1 <- text %>% ungroup %>% arrange(file_num, n) %>%
            mutate(order = row_number()) # create variable order 

ggplot(text1,aes(order, n, fill = file_num)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_x_continuous(
        breaks = text1$order,
        labels = text1$word,
        expand = c(0,0),
        xlab("Word")) +
    facet_grid(file_num ~ ., scales = "free") +
    coord_flip()
```

Output plot:
[image]