# How to order boxplots by the x-axis-values within every facet in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

I want to sort the boxplots by the x-axis-values (hwy here) within every facet (class here). I tried 2 methods, but failed:

```
library(tidyverse); library(forcats)

mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = fct_reorder(trans, hwy, median))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free_y")

mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  mutate(trans = fct_reorder(trans, hwy, median)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = trans)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free_y")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214071/how-to-order-data-by-value-within-ggplot-facets

Comment: Thanks Tung! I want to be able to use fct_reorder. Am i using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tung, that link gave me the clue! The function reorder_within from the tidytext was useful here:

```
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = tidytext::reorder_within(trans, hwy, class, median))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free_y")
```

...but the only problem now is the text _class got attached to every y-value on the chart? Is there a way to fix that?